# How do I set the colour, font and size of a prompt-text string?

Tags: java, javafx, prompt

I am trying to change the properties of a String made from `TextField::setPromptText` using JavaFX.

This code:

```
TextField shapeField = new TextField();         
shapeField.setMaxWidth(100);   
shapeField.setPromptText("Circle, Triangle, Hexagon");
             
TextField fillField = new TextField();         
fillField.setMaxWidth(100);
fillField.setPromptText("Red, Green, Grey");
```

Currently sets the prompt text to this:

[image: prompt text]

I want to be able to make the font smaller and change the colour. How would I do this?

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textinputcontrol .. for color

Comment: .. using a different font is not supported by default: TextInputControlSkin binds the font of the (visual rep) of the prompt to the skinnable's font. So you would need a custom skin that allows modifying it separately

Comment: @Abra probably wasn't clear enough: what I meant is the font used for the promptText that's different from the font used for the text

Answer (score -1):

For color you need:
-fx-prompt-text-fill: red;
and you can change font size with but you need to add an event to check if text is empty then use your prompt text size and when not the actual size of the text (edited):
-fx-font-size

for example:

```
tf.setStyle("-fx-prompt-text-fill: red;\n" + "-fx-font-size: 26pt;");
```

Comment: this changes the font size of the text (vs. only the font size of the prompt-text as required in the question)

Comment: ok. but you can change it back when textField !isEmpty() because prompt text show only when textField is Empty.

Comment: concededly possible (though probably has visible side-effects on layout, but then that's another story) - please edit your answer with an outline of what's needed (best as [mcve])